# Does clip-path work on Safari / Internet Explorer / Edge?

Tags: html, css

I have the snippet of code below.

I just want to generate the `top-left` corner of a frame using one image fragment.

This code works perfectly on: `Firefox / Chrome` but **DOES NOT** work well on: `Safari / Internet Explorer / Edge`.

```css
.frame {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
.trapezoid-top, .trapezoid-left {
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/dNUCFd/fragment.png");
    background-size: contain;
}
.trapezoid-top {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 40px 100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.trapezoid-left {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 40px 100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
 <div class="edge_top_left">
  <div class="trapezoid-top"></div>
  <div class="trapezoid-left"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should be:

[image]

And this is how it got rendered on: `Safari / Internet Explorer / Edge`:

[image]

Just in case, here you have the `JSFiddle`:

https://jsfiddle.net/0skhbhok/

In case it is possible to fix this, could you modify my code in order it works on all platforms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to sources: [Here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

`clip-path` seems to work (mostly partially) on most browsers, except IE, Edge, and Opera Mini.